# In Haxe, is it possible to make an array readonly for other classes?

Tags: haxe

We have `haxe.ds.ReadOnlyArray`, but it blocks push/pop for everyone. What I need is to be able to change it within a class, but not outside of it. Is it possible? When I do `public var myArr(default, null):Array<Something>` - it won't let other classes replace the array itself, but they can push/pop, so it's not a solution, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expose it as a read-only array to the outside by using a read-only property that has a different name:

```
var internalArray:Array<T>;

public var publicArray(get, never):haxe.ds.ReadOnlyArray<T>;

function get_publicArray() return internalArray;
```

Comment: what if someone does
```haxe
var hey:Array<T> = obj.publicArray;
hey.push(new T())
```
will they be able to do this?

Comment: The implicit cast only works in one direction, so not without an explicit `cast`.